# Какой Activity запускается первым?

Tags: android

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста, где в проекте указывается, какой activity запускается первым.

Answer (score 4):

в файле **AndroidManifest.xml** вот так:

```
<activity
    android:name="LoginActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: *AndroidManifest.xml, а то не найдет